# Bash Script: Help find the bug

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to run this script to for an import action via RightScale's API, but it keeps reporting "BAD Request 400" for the second CURL operation, and it looks like the URL isn't forming correctly. I've also tried putting the POST URL in double-quotes, but that didn't change the result.

Both AccountList.txt and TemplateList.txt have account numbers and template numbers respectively, one on each line. To debug, I've only put one account number and template number in each file, respectively.

Please help me understand what's wrong with this piece of code. I'm guessing it's something trivial, but I can't understand what that is:

```
cat "AccountList.txt" | while read acc ; do
        rm scriptcookie
        curl -i -H 'X-API-VERSION:1.5' -c scriptcookie -d email="emailid@company.com" -d password="p@sswd" -X POST -d account_href="/api/accounts/$acc" https://my.rightscale.com/api/sessions 

        cat "TemplateList.txt" | while read temp ; do   
                echo $temp
                curl -i -H 'X_API_VERSION:1.5' -b ./scriptcookie -X POST https://my.rightscale.com/api/publications/$temp/import

        done
echo "Done for Account:" $acc    
done
```

This is the output I'm seeing:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm thinking there's something going on with BASH on my machine.

I just tried to echo the entire CURL line within the script:

echo "curl -i -H 'X_API_VERSION:1.5' -b ./scriptcookie -X POST https://my.rightscale.com/api/publications/$temp/import"

and I got this as output:

/import -H 'X_API_VERSION:1.5' -b ./scriptcookie -X POST https://my.rightscale.com/api/publications/184605

Comment: Try adding "-xv" flags after the shebang to assist in debugging, like this "#!/bin/bash -xv"

Comment: @MarkSetchell. I added "-xv" to the shebang and it prints the entire script and then this: http://i60.tinypic.com/292m9ns.png

Thank you!

Comment: Notice the "/r" at the end of :

echo $'184605\r'

For some reason, the script seems to be taking a carriage return when accessing $temp.

I just tried running this exact script on Cygwin on Windows and the script is flying. Something is fishy here

Comment: `dos2unix file` for any file that has been within eyesight of a windows machine. Also best to update  your question rather than hope that people will spend the time plowing thru an ever growing thread of comments, somoe of which change the over problem definition. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my version of bash (4.1.5) from Debian Squeeze was inserting a carriage return '/r' character to the $temp variable.

I figured this out when I ran the same script on Cygwin for Windows and the script ran without issues. Also thanks to @Mark Setchell for suggesting the "-xv" flag without which I'd have never figured out the cause.

This is a comparison between the "echo $temp" line on Debian v/s Cygwin:

Debian (bash-4.1.5):

```
++ echo $'184605\r'
```

Cygwin (bash-4.1.11):

```
+ echo 184605
```

Why is this the case? I can't answer that, but I'm glad I figured out it's to do with Bash version itself. Thanks to all!